# Is there any harm/downside to using slots 2 and 4 in a dual channel PC configuration even though it is not listed as an option in the user manual?

Tags: memory

I have a desktop that I built well over a decade ago. It has a Gigabyte GA-EX58-UD3R motherboard and uses DDR3. I had 2x4GB dual channel memory in it.

I recently purchased and installed 2x8GB and Windows 10 was showing 16GB installed and 8GB usable. When I put back the original 2x4GB, it said 8GB installed and 4GB usable.

I deduced that slot 1 somehow had gone bad so I'm not using slots 2 and 4 and things seem to be working (all installed memory is recognized/usable).

My question is, is there any harm/downside to using slots 2 and 4 in a dual channel configuration even though it is not listed as an option in the user manual?

According to the manual, slot 1 should always be used in any configuration.

Also, is there a performance hit going to the higher slot number vs slot 1?

[image]

Comment: Slots 2 and 4 wouldn’t result in a dual channel configuration on that motherboard. The difference is hardware reserved. You just need to configure your firmware differently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen many 3-channel motherboards that according to the manual always should have 1 stick (of a pair) in channel 1.

They would work fine in any combination of the stick accross the slots, BUT would not operate in dual-channel mode if slot 1 wasn't populated.

Seems yours is the same: With the RAM in 2 and 4 it will work, but in single channel mode only.

That will halve the RAM performance. It will depend on your usage of the machine if that is really noticeable or not.