# Memory 16GB installed and 8GB usable

Tags: memory

I have a very old desktop with a Gigabyte GA-EX58-UD3R motherboard. I had 2x4GB dual channel memory in it.

I purchased and installed 2x8GB and Windows 10 was showing 16GB installed and 8GB usable. BIOS was also only recognizing 8GB.

I then put back the original 2x4GB, and Windows now says 8GB installed and 4GB usable (there was no unusable memory before).

What happened?

Things were good then suddenly only half the RAM is usable. It seems that slot 1 is the unusable slot because if I boot up with memory installed in just that slot, Windows doesn't start.

Installing in slots 2 and/or 4 work but that is a single channel config.

[image]

Comment: Is this the same question as [this other one you posted](https://superuser.com/q/1836374/167207)?

Comment: No, different questions on the same larger issue.